# Resolving Subversion error E235000 - Cannot update anymore

Tags: svn, version

I am working with the latest version of Subversion (SVN v1.7.5) and all of a sudden, I can no longer update. When I attempt to update, I get:

E235000: Assertion failed at line 1538

This is preventing me from updating my existing working copies. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in node handling where certain conditions are erroneously marked as invalid.

Your best bet is to rebuild SVN from scratch. Download the source from Apache.org and make the following changes to the source:

```
$ diff -u update_editor.orig update_editor.c 
--- update_editor.orig 2012-04-26 13:02:08.000000000 +0900
+++ update_editor.c  2012-05-30 02:27:24.000000000 +0900
@@ -1578,9 +1578,8 @@
     /* When the node existed before (it was locally deleted, replaced or
      * edited), then 'update' cannot add it "again". So it can only send
      * _action_edit, _delete or _replace. */
-    SVN_ERR_ASSERT(action == svn_wc_conflict_action_edit
-                   || action == svn_wc_conflict_action_delete
-                   || action == svn_wc_conflict_action_replace);
+    ;
+
   else if (reason == svn_wc_conflict_reason_added)
     /* When the node did not exist before (it was locally added), then 'update'
      * cannot want to modify it in any way. It can only send _action_add. */
```

Finally, you can build the client only (and not the server) with the following command:

```
./configure \
--without-berkeley-db \
--without-apache \
--without-apxs \
--without-swig \
--with-ssl

make

make install
```

You might be better off using a tool like **src2pkg** or **checkinstall** in place of the "make install" command so you can uninstall it painlessly later. This patch is not ideal, but it gets the job done.

**Sources:**

- SVN Source:
  http://subversion.apache.org/
- Building JUST the SVN client from source without the server components:
  http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1249332:
- Patch to correct issue in SVN 1.7.5
  http://dqn.sakusakutto.jp/2012/05/svn_E235000_In_file_subversion_libsvn_wc_update_editor.c_line_1583%20.html

Comment: Glad it helped. I originally applied this patch and went through all this work while helping a client with an 11'th hour SVN client upgrade. Re-CO'ing the source would have taken too long. Hope it helped other people in a bind :)

Comment: Our whole team (20+ devs) is running your patch, and have been instructed not to apt-get the production svn :) -- do you know what the status of the official fix is?

Comment: Sorry, nope. I'm more of a driver dev. I don't commit to production Subversion. The only suggestion I have at this point is stick to client version 1.6. I took this route because I ended up upgrading 400GB of source which I can only acquire over a very unreliable link. The upgrade took a weekend, while re-checking out would take a month.